# What does "revision is due by" mean?

Tags: peer-review, open-access

I got a minor revision with the message "Your revision is due by 19 Oct 2022." I sent the comments in by Sept. 23.

Will I have to wait until Oct. 19 for an update, as the status still with the editor?  Does this message mean the revision will be reviewed in this period or after this period, as I need the acceptance before the end of October.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means that if you don't send your revision by 19 October, they might start doing other things (such as assume you are no longer interested in revising your manuscript).

It does not mean that you will get a decision by 19 October, or that they will start working on your paper on 19 October if you send in a revision early.

If you need the paper accepted (more precisely, a final decision) by the end of October, you can send them a message asking if they can expedite the paper. It's possible they can, also possible they won't.

Comment: I would add that these dates are often negotiable, especially for major revisions and when new experiments or analysis need to be performed. My impression is that the date is mostly to ensure that a paper doesn't sit on the journal's books forever.

Comment: @Matt yeah from my experience working in academic publishing, your impression is spot on. If the authors ask for an extension we are generally happy to grant it, and the due date really only comes up when we do "spring cleaning" and remove all the inactive manuscripts.

Comment: @user1 it's not abnormal. You just say you need a decision quickly because of [insert reasons], just be warned that they might say it's not possible to expedite the paper that much, and there's no guarantee the decision will be "accept".

Comment: @Allure: are there really "inactive manuscripts"? That's surprising to me. It's hard imagining myself as taking all the effort to write a manuscript to later quit just before publication.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yeah, there are. I don't think the authors give up on publication entirely, but they might give up on publication in that journal - effectively withdrawing the manuscript by never submitting a revision.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I have one floating around because all the key players left the institution/academia and so whoever is the first author now might not have cared enough / had the time/resources to prioritize it.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro There are also manuscripts where you intend to do some additional experiments, revise, and resubmit, but you have other papers and proposal deadlines...and then a year has passed and you still haven't done any revision.